# c++ Qt running code with opncv

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am new to Qt and don't know yet how to really use it correctly.

I am trying to run this code : (in the up right corner - download)
https://googledrive.com/host/0By56j-W37_RAYS1DcVl3MnFRZGc/index.html

in the website written :
"Technical Requirements : OpenCV 2.4.5  ... Qt 5.0.2 (32 bit) ... Qt Creator 2.7.0 (included with the indicated version of Qt)  ... Additionally, in order to compile the OpenCV source code and install it, you will need CMake.

I have downloaded Qt5.3.0 , I have opencv 2.4.8 (worked and tested) , have CMake installed and also have VS2012.

in the zip file (source) , there is many files (cpp,h,ui,pro,user ....).

The problem is that I don't know which files should be deleted and what files should be edited (to compile in my environment) - and how to compile it (in Qt Creator or VS) ?

If anyone ,who's familiar with Qt, can take a fast look on the zip file to tell me what to do it will be great.

I will very appreciate help with this,
Thanks

Comment: now I have another problem : warning: Error opening file (../../modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:545)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application.pro seems to be the main project file.

Open it with QtCreator.

You may want to open Application.pro with a text editor first and adjust following lines, and specify the path where you installed OpenCV and the respective version (replace 245 with 248).

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenCV/include
DEPENDPATH += C:/OpenCV/include

LIBS += -LC:/OpenCV/bin

LIBS += -lopencv_calib3d245
...
LIBS += -lopencv_videostab245d
```

Comment: Thanks , I also needed to delete all files except cpp,h,ui,and pro .
so I can run the application.
but now I have another problem : warning: Error opening file (../../modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:545)